# How to reduce the query execution time in mysql

Tags: mysql

How to reduce the query execution time in mysql where table having records greater than 154381 and inner query should be used

This is my Query :

```
SELECT txn_gallery.gallery_image 
FROM txn_gallery 
WHERE villa_id IN(SELECT villa_id 
                  FROM txn_notifications 
                  LEFT JOIN mst_villa on mst_villa.sk_villa_id=txn_notifications.villa_id 
                  WHERE txn_notifications.member_id='235' and txn_notifications.tran_status='Approved')
```

Comment: Show output of `show create table thetablename` for all three tables

Comment: ..and the result of `EXPLAIN [your query]`

Comment: There is no point LEFT JOINing a table from which you select no columns.

Comment: @Strawberry ah, you are right.  This message will self-destruct

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your query is functionally identical to:

```
SELECT g.gallery_image 
  FROM txn_gallery g
  JOIN txn_notifications n
    ON n.villa_id = g.villa_id
 WHERE n.member_id = 235
   and n.tran_status = 'Approved'
```

An index on some combination of (villa_id,member_id,tran_status) would be useful

Comment: Thank tou it works fine and reduced the query exection time

Answer (score 1):

Its better to use join instead of inner query

JOIN can be faster than an equivalent subquery because the server might be able to optimize it better

So subqueries can be slower than LEFT [OUTER] JOIN

Comment: Can be, yes, but are not likely to be in this case.  With the right indexes, this query should be fine either way